# Rails -- create and create! methods, RoR 3 Tutorial

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

So I know the distinction between the bang (exclamation mark) and non-bang methods usually is whether the method will modify the object itself or return a separate modified object keeping the original unchanged.

Then while building the User model in chapter 6 of the book, I came across the `User.create` method, which creates a new model and saves it to the database in a single step.  In Michael Hartl's *Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial*, he writes that the `User.create!` method "works just like the `create` method...except that it raises an **ActiveRecord::Record-Invalid** exception if the creation fails."

I'm pretty confused.  Is the `User.create!` method not following Ruby "bang-convention" or am I completely missing something?  And if he IS following the convention, how does `User.create!` modify  self if it is a class method?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Though a lot of classes treat bang methods as "a method that modifies the object in place", I like the description of bang methods from the [Eloquent Ruby book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321584104) better:

> In practice, Ruby programmers reserve
>   ! to adorn the names of methods that do
>   something unexpected, or perhaps a bit
>   dangerous

So in this case, the "unexpected" result is that an exception is raised instead of just failing and returning `false`.

Answer (score 21):

Hope this helps as well:

> The bang versions (e.g. save!) raise an exception if the record is invalid. The non-bang versions don’t: save and update_attributes return false, create and update just return the objects.

Source: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark

**Edit: Changed source to fix broken link**