# Rails Validations that Inform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I added a validation after already having data in my db. It required the presence of an association and one of my records didn't have the said association. When I tried to update it, Rails returned `false` so I knew it wasn't updating but when I checked the log all I got was:

```
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 Aka Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "akas".* FROM "akas"  WHERE "akas"."sid" = $1  [["sid", 144]]
  (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

It took me a while to realise what was happening. Is there some way to get the validations to tell me what is wrong?

**Update for googlers:** see [Rails -- create and create! methods, RoR 3 Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316821/rails-create-and-create-methods-ror-3-tutorial) - it begins to explain differences in bang methods (update_attributes vs update_attributes!), I found it helpful (and I'm using RoR v4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The validation message option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message):

> ... the :message option lets you specify the message that will be added to the errors collection when validation fails. When this option is not used, Active Record will use the respective default error message for each validation helper.

E.g.

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true, message: 'not unique'
```

Comment: Was there an error that I missed then because this implies an error should be raised and I'm pretty sure that there wasn't one

Comment: Some ways to save data raise errors (e.g. `save!`) and others do not (`save`).

Comment: Apparently `update_attributes` is another that does not